# Conditional operator for an operator

Tags: javascript, operators, ternary

I have a piece of code:

```
if (foo > bar) {
    baz = foo - bar
} else {
    baz = foo + bar
}
```

I have a question if I can somehow shorten this code to a single line, something like

> PSEUDOCODE:

```
baz = foo (foo > bar ? + : -) bar
```

> Real code I'd like to shorten

```
if (gradientStartH > gradientEndH) {
    h = gradientStartH - Math.abs(gradientStartH - gradientEndH) / arr.length * i
} else {
    h = gradientStartH + Math.abs(gradientStartH - gradientEndH) / arr.length * i
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If the operation is "much more complicated", a ternary should be avoided, for readability and maintainability reasons

Comment: `baz = (foo > bar) ? (foo - bar) : (foo + bar)` ?

Comment: @Taplar maybe you are right! But please take a look on real code example that I'd like to "enhance"

Answer (score 4):

```
baz = foo > bar ? foo - bar : foo + bar;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

**EDIT:**

I understand your specific question. I'm pretty sure I'm going to get lynched for saying this, but you could use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to evaluate it as a string. Not recommend, if any of the below derives via [unsantized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanitization_(classified_information)) user data.

```
h = eval(`${gradientStartH} ${gradientStartH > gradientEndH ? '-' : '+'} ${Math.abs(gradientStartH - gradientEndH) / arr.length * i}`);
```

Otherwise a decent two liner. Preferred.

```
const absVal = Math.abs(gradientStartH - gradientEndH) / arr.length * i;
h = gradientStartH > gradientEndH ? gradientStartH - absVal : gradientStartH + absVal;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could convert the check to a number or take `-1` as factor.

```
baz = foo + (foo > bar || -1) * bar
```

The cleanest approach is to use an object with the operands and a check for getting the operands.

```
op = {
    true: function (a, b) { return a + b; }, // add
    false: function (a, b) { return a - b; } // sub
}
baz = op[foo > bar](foo, bar);
```

Comment: You probably mean `object` i guess there's a typo in your answer, +1 nice answer

Answer (score 4):

You were almost there. `foo - bar` could be written as `foo + -bar`. So the pseudo code could be written as:

```
baz = foo + (foo > bar ? +1 : -1) * bar
```

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the `if-else` and `Math.abs` to just this:

```
h = gradientStartH - (gradientStartH - gradientEndH) / arr.length * i
```

Here's a snippet comparing it with your code:

```js
// Your code 
function getDiffExisting(gradientStartH, gradientEndH, arr) {
  let h = 0;
  
  if (gradientStartH > gradientEndH) {
    h = gradientStartH - Math.abs(gradientStartH - gradientEndH) / arr.length
  } else {
    h = gradientStartH + Math.abs(gradientStartH - gradientEndH) / arr.length
  }
  
  return h;
}

console.log(getDiffExisting(200, 100, [1,2]))
console.log(getDiffExisting(50, 100, [1,2]))

function getDiffNew(gradientStartH, gradientEndH, arr) {
  let h = gradientStartH - (gradientStartH - gradientEndH) / arr.length
  return h;
}

console.log(getDiffNew(200, 100, [1,2]))
console.log(getDiffNew(50, 100, [1,2]))
```

(I have removed the `i` for testing purposes)

Comment: You're welcome. You can [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left

Answer (score 2):

Something like this,

```
baz = foo > bar ? foo - bar : foo + bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ternary operator, as you attempted in your original answer. The syntax for a ternary operator should be `condition ? true : false;`

```
baz = foo > bar ? foo-bar : foo+bar;
```

You mentioned that it "might be much more complicated than this" which does not allow much clarity for a solution. Ternary operators likely will **not** work depending on the complexity. You can read more about ternary operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: That was a pseudo code of how it would be look like so I could better explain myself